# Sharepoint-Word ContentTypeProperties

Tags: vba, ms-word, sharepoint-online

I like using the Document Sets in Sharepoint (online 365 version).  A document placed in a document set picks up the columns on the document set as metadata, which helps with form production.  I have been able to access this metadata in VBA (to assemble text blocks, etc...) using the first line bwlow.

This is just not working now, and I can't figure out why.  I am getting an error:  "Method 'value' of object 'Metaproperty' failed".

I am trying to just debug.print it, and this generally works in other (older) documents.

I have also tried the second set of code, which also works in older documents, but now throws an error:  element not found

Anyone have any ideas for me?  Am I possibly missing a reference library in VBA?

1. ActiveDocument.ContentTypeProperties("*column name*").Value

or

2. Dim sp As MetaProperties
   Set sp = ActiveDocument.ContentTypeProperties
   Debug.Print sp("*column name*")

Comment: This is specifically a Sharepoint question, perhaps better asked at [Sharepoint SE](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: ISTR this happens when the .Value Property (a Variant)  is not a scalar value (e.g. a single number or string) but an array or structure, Can't check what I used to do right now but I think in VBA in simple cases you might be able to assume that the Variant is an array, otherwise, you may have to get the values from the relevant Custom XML Part, possibly using the Schem info. in the MetaProperties.SchemaXml property.